# What is the equivalent of this kotlin code in dart?

Tags: kotlin, dart

In kotlin I was able to create a method like this.

```
fun add(a:int, b:int, output: (int) -> Unit {
  val sum = a + b
  output.invoke(sum)
}
```

Then I could call this method like this:

```
add(4,5){ sum ->
  print(sum) //9
}
```

Is this possible in dart?
I have looked at a lot of sources but havn't been able to find any help.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That Kotlin syntax looks fishy, there must be missing brackets. I don't know Kotlin, but I think you want this:

```
void add(int a, int b, Function(int) output) {
  final sum = a + b;
  output.call(sum);
}

void main() {
  add(4,5, (sum) => print(sum));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's pretty simple. Silly me.

```
void add(int a, int b, void c(int)) {
  return c.call(5);
}
```